# VS 2015 Command Prompt Error:"the filename,directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Tags: visual-studio

### Added a command prompt to VS 2015 with these instructions:

```
Open Tools -> “External Tools…”
Click “Add”
```

Enter the following information into the new tool screen:
Field   Value
Title   VS Command Prompt
Command:    C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
Arguments:  /k “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat”
Initial Directory:  $(SolutionDir)

Save your changes (and re-order your tools to suit your preferences). The “VS Command Prompt” will now be available in:

### Tools -> VS Command Prompt

Every time the prompt is opened, it shows the error "the filename,directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect".

Is there anything else I can do in VS or add a path to the environment variables?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the argument 
/k “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat”

It should be 
/k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"

I encountered the same problem when I copied the argument from the website
https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/06/add-visual-studio-command-prompt-to-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: Solved by @Frankie. Thanks.